# Variable does not return desired object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an Express app. I currently have an error in the following file, `factoryRepository.js`

```
let appReference = null;

module.exports.init = (app) => {
  appReference = app;
};

module.exports.getRepositoryFactory = () => {

  let repositoryFactory = {

    getUserRepository: () => {
      return require("./UserRepository").init(appReference.get('models').User);
    }

  };

  return repositoryFactory;
};
```

`appReference.get` throws a TypeError because `appReference` is still `null` even after I have called `module.exports.init` somewhere else.

I have tried to make a function that returns `appReference` so I can see in what state it is. I have been able to get `app` rather than `null`, it is only in the context of `getUserRepository` that it stays `null`.

The faulty line is only called when I ping a certain route.

EDIT:

This is `app.js`, the context from which `module.exports.init` is being called

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import config from './config/config';

let app = express();

// Setup models
app.set('models', require('./app/models'));
require('./app/repo/repositoryFactory').init(app);
// Setup config
require('./config/init')(app);
// Setup routes
require('./app/routes')(app, passport);
// Setup passport
require('./app/auth')(passport, config);
// Route to ends
require('./config/endpoints')(app);

export default app;
```

`public.js` is the logic given to my router, and it is here where I call the faulty code with `repositoryFactory.getUserRepository()`

```
let repositoryFactory = require('../repo/RepositoryFactory').getRepositoryFactory();

module.exports.doLogin = (req, res) => {
  let success = () => {
    res.redirect('/');
  };

  let error = (message) => {
    res.status(500).json(message);
  };

  let userRepository = repositoryFactory.getUserRepository();
  userRepository.findOrCreate({
    facebookId: req.user.id,
    displayName: req.user.displayName
  }, success, error);
};

module.exports.doLogout = (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'You\'ve succesfully logged out.'
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code around your call to `init()`? Is it nested in something asynchronous perhaps? Maybe put some logging inside `init()` so that you can confirm that it is being called before `getRepositoryFactory()` and not merely being queued in the event loop?

Comment: @Trott I have edited with the context from which `module.exports.init` and `module.exports.getRepositoryFactory`. I have logged from within `module.exports.init` and it was successfully called.

Comment: How are you enabling ES6 modules? They are not enabled in Node by default.

Comment: @Trott I use `babel-node` to run the code.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal amount of code that someone can actually run to reproduce the bug? There's still missing context here, like the router information. If I can't reproduce the bug, I'd rather not guess what the problem is. Guessing anyway, the two obvious guesses are either something asynchronous causes your functions to run in a different order than you think, or (the more likely one) a scope issue where the `factoryRepository` in app.js is a different instance than the one in public.js. You might want to use dependency injection just to make sure they are the same.

Comment: In fact, the scope issue is almost definitely what it is. Let me see if I can throw together a quick express demonstration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a scope issue. Let's say we simplify your three files as follows, and also put them all in the same directory (for simplicity here):

app.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');

let app = express();

require('./repositoryFactory').init(app);

const myPublic = require('./public');
```

repositoryFactory.js:

```
'use strict';
let appReference = null;

module.exports.init = (app) => {
  appReference = app;
};

module.exports.getRepositoryFactory = () => {
    return appReference ? 'I have an app reference!' : 'No app reference!';
};
```

public.js:

```
'use strict';
let repositoryFactory = require('./RepositoryFactory').getRepositoryFactory();

console.log(repositoryFactory);
```

This is going to log `No app reference!` because the `repositoryFactory` is not a singleton. The `repositoryFactory` instance in `app.js` is a different instance than the `repositoryFactory` instance in public.js.

One solution would be to pass a parameter for the `repositoryFactory` instance. repositoryFactory.js would be unchanged, but app.js might look like this:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');

let app = express();

const repositoryFactory = require('./repositoryFactory')
repositoryFactory.init(app);

const myPublic = require('./public');
myPublic.init(repositoryFactory);
myPublic.log();
```

And the corresponding public.js might look like this:

```
'use strict';
let repositoryFactory = null;

module.exports.init = (myRepositoryFactory) => {
  repositoryFactory = myRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryFactory();
}

module.exports.log = () => {
  console.log(repositoryFactory);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented a solution similar to your proposal, but I'm still confused because I tried watering it down to three simple JS files with the same pattern, it kept the same instance throughout all of the files. Also, I was trying to emulate the same pattern I saw at an example in [github](https://github.com/jacruzca/node-express-sequelize-boilerplate/blob/master/app%2Frepository%2FRepositoryFactory.js). Thanks nonetheless!